# maximizing the negative norm is it convex problem?

Tags: convex-optimization, matlab, nonlinear-optimization

I have an objective function with two decision variables x1 and x2

\begin{equation} 
\begin{array}{cl}
\underset{\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2}}{ \max}  a_1x_1+ a_2x_2 -c\sqrt{h_{1}(x) ^2 + h_{2}(x)^2}  \\ 
\text { s.t. }  x_{1}+x_{2}=1 
\end{array}
\end{equation}

I tried to introduce new variables
$b_1=h_1(x) ,b_2=h_2(x) $ so my objective function will be

\begin{array}{cl}
\underset{\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2}}{ \max}  a_1x_1+ a_2x_2 -cu  \\ 
\text { s.t. }  x_{1}+x_{2}=1 ,\\
 h_1(x)=b_1, \\ 
h_2(x)=b_2 ,\\
 \sqrt{b_1^2 + b_2^2 } \leq u 
\end{array}

my questions:

1. does the reformulation with the new constraints correct ?
2. because I am maximizing the negative norm does that mean it is a convex function ?
3. how can I solve my problem in MATLAB

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the optimization problem! Is it over a or over x? If it is over a the constraint does not make any difference at all! What about the functions $h_{1}, h_{2}$? Are they functions of x and therefore constant in optimization over a? Please explain!!

Comment: my variable x1,x2 , however a and c are constants. h1,h2 are linear function of x

Comment: OK my answer applies and in this case! And things are simplified because of linearity, but you have the squares which make it a little complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $c$ is positive, it is a simple SOCP-representable convex problem. I would not be surprised if you can solve it analytically but otherwise solve it using an SOCP solver (or just use any nonlinear solver, it is easy enough)

Using YALMIP in MATLAB, you would just write

```
sdpvar x1 x2
h1 = ...
h2 = ...
Constraints= [x1+x2==1];
Objective = (a1*x1+a2*x2 - c*norm([h1;h2]);
optimize(Constraints,-Objective);
```

Comment: thank you, but how about the other two constraints: h1(x)=b1,h2(x)=b2 ? and when I wrote norm does that mean I will not include the  square ? I run the code but I received an error  :  
                                                               
 Objective = (-0.9338291*x1-1.3395790*x2 - 1.645*norm([h1;h2]);
                                                                                                       ↑
Error: Invalid expression. When calling a function or indexing a variable, use
parentheses. Otherwise, check for mismatched delimiters.

Comment: I think I found the problem with error , its regarding one of the parentheses was missing, however I am not sure about the  other two constraints: h1(x)=b1,h2(x)=b2 , why we dont need to add them to the code

Comment: The code has placeholders where you have to define h1 and h2. The variables b1 and b2 are just some auxilliary variables you introduced.

Comment: yes I defined them. Thank you

Comment: when I tried to check my objective function it gave me : Nonlinear scalar (real, 3 variables)
Current value: -1.1674
Coefficients range: 0.93383 to 1.645  ,,, does that mean my objective value is -1.1674 ? but what  does coefficient range means ?  because I wrote value([x1;x2])
and it gave me different values for x1 and x2

Comment: You are now posting questions more suitable for YALMIP specific forums.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly the optimization is over $(x_{1},x_{2})$ and not over $(a_{1},\,a_{2})$ because in the last case max=$+\infty$.

Just use the linear constraint and write $x_{2}=1-x$. Then we get

max $a_{1}x+a_{2}(1-x)-c\sqrt{H_{1}^{2}(x)+H_{2}^{2}(x)}$

where $H_{1}(x)=h_{1}(x,1-x)$ and $H_{2}(x)=h_{2}(x,1-x)$

which can be solved in the standard way by considering derivative of the function and finding stationary points, which is:

$a_{1}-a_{2}-c\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{H_{1}^{2}(x)+H_{2}^{2}}(x)}(2H_{1}(x)H_{1}'(x)+2H_{2}(x)H_{2}'(x))=0$

Solving the last equality you get some stationary points and by considering second derivative you will decide which is the maximum! But it all depends on functions $\, h_{1},\,h_{2}$.

Comment: but with the square root this is a nonlinear optimization, am I correct ?